# php create empty JSONarray

Tags: php, json

How do I create an empty JSON array?

I tried `$finalJSON["items"][0] =  '';` but that gave me `{"items":[""]}`

I tried `$finalJSON["items"][0] =  null;` but that gave me `{"items":[null]}`

What I actually want is `{"items":[]}`

How to achieve this?

Comment: There is no such thing as "`JSON` array" (or "`JSON` object"). `JSON` is a portable text representation of some data structure. If you want to encode as `JSON` an empty array then create an empty array (`array()` or `[]` on [PHP 5.4 and newer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)) and encode it using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code actually creates an array with already one element with key 0 and value '' (empty string) or null. Instead, use:

```
$finalJSON["items"] = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$arr['items'] = array();
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```
<?php
$items = [];
echo json_encode($items);
```

The output is: `[]`.

That is the "most empty" array you can create and convert into a json encoding.

So if you want such an array as value inside an object as property `item`, then use an object:

```
<?php
class myObject {
  public $items = [];
}
echo json_encode(new myObject);
```

The output is: `{"items":[]}`

Answer (score 1):

You should set an empty array:

```
$finalJSON = [];
$finalJSON["items"] = [];

echo json_encode($finalJSON);
```

Output:

```
{"items":[]}
```

[Example](https://eval.in/420966)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<?php
$finalJSON["items"] =  array();
echo json_encode($finalJSON);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$finalJSON["items"] =  []; //short syntax
```

or

```
$finalJSON["items"] =  array(); //old syntax
```

and to output:

```
echo json_encode($finalJSON);
```